# Graded symmetric and antisymmetric tensors

Tags: tensors

For a vector space V let V^v be its dual.

Then let Grad^k(V^v) be the subspace of graded symmetric tensors.What this means?

Similarly for graded antisymmetric tensors.

Thanks!

Comment: the 1st  could be the vector space of symmetric rank $k$ tensors over $V$, similarly for the 2nd.